# In Matplotlib, How to avoid axvspan overlap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I noticed that two adjacent areas overlap, so in the middle appear an annoying line.
I tried "capstyle = 'butt'" which I used to avoid overlap between lines, but here it doesn't do the job.

here's a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax.axvspan(0, 0.5, color = 'red', alpha = 0.13, capstyle = 'butt')
ax.axvspan(0.5, 1, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.13, capstyle = 'butt')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem you have is not due to line caps, since axvspan draws a polygon. The problem is that this polygon, by default, has a border with a given linewidth (one pixel, I suppose).

So, to get just the areas without that "border", set the linewidth (`lw`) to zero:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax.axvspan(0, 0.5, color = 'red', alpha = 0.13, lw=0)
ax.axvspan(0.5, 1, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.13, lw=0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dv1kApvEPiY&ab_channel=lucnatang

Answer (score 10):

Instead of `color`, use `facecolor` inside `axvspan`. The solution by @heltonbiker works great, it gets rid of the width of the border. But, at least in the matplotlib version I'm using, 2.0.0, using just `facecolor` doesn't draw the border.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.axvspan(0, 0.5, facecolor = 'red', alpha = 0.13)
ax.axvspan(0.5, 1, facecolor = 'blue', alpha = 0.13)

plt.show()
```

Using only `facecolor` will no draw the border:
[image]

Using `color` will fill the rectangle and will draw a border:
[image]

Comment: Could be,.. I'm using version 1.5.1 and the line is present.